# MySQL which is the method to rollback a transaction effective?

Tags: mysql, transactions, sql-update, innodb, sql-insert

I saw in multiple answers here and on google that rollback a transaction implies only the rollback of the last command, and i read also that implies ALL commands. (neither both documented or referenced by)

That I need to do is create a store procedure that insert/update on table A, get the last ID of A, insert that ID into B, get the last id of B, insert it into C, etc, etc, etc.

I want to know which is the method to commit or rollback all commands in the transaction, in order to start the transaction and if something fails, get back everything as the original.

SQL code with IF error and last_id will be preciated, because also I saw a LOT of differents ways to get the last id and I don't know which is better.

By the way, all tables are **InnoDB**

Kind regards,

Comment: You need to turn off autocommit. Then a set of updates can be committed as a single transaction. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: by the official documentation, autocommit is set to off if you do a "start transaction". is not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `BEGIN` a transaction then nothing will get applied until you `COMMIT` it. Dropping your connection or issuing a `ROLLBACK` is the same as never committing it.

This is, of course, presuming you have `autocommit` set on, which is usually the case.

You can roll-back individual commands if you wrap them as transactions as well.

More information is available in [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html).

Keep in mind that MyISAM and other engines do not support transactions, where InnoDB does. Further, only `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `REPLACE` statements are able to be rolled back. Other things, like alterations to the schema, are not.

Comment: if you use start transaction, the autocommit sets to off, says the documentation. It's true? which is better? start or begin transaction? +1 by the way

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about `autocommit` being toggled during a transaction. Just issue a `BEGIN`, a series of operations, and a `COMMIT` if you're prepared to make it permanent. If you encounter errors during the operations, you can either recover or abort the transaction.

Comment: excellent. What method you can suggest to check if there was error and be secure? Because I read three or four method, with the doubt of the "last error" or "some error", I need "any error"

Comment: It depends entirely on your driver. Some will raise an exception, some will return an error code, while others you'll have to check the status of your query result or statement handle. The MySQL C driver, on which many are based, has a last error method that can be interrogated, so not surprisingly many drivers follow this convention.

Comment: I'm thinking creating store procedures

Comment: That's usually overkill. Have a look at what your database driver can do, or find a wrapper class or ORM that can manage a lot of this for you. It's usually almost effortless in the proper framework.

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`START TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT`, and `ROLLBACK` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/commit.html):

> These statements provide control over use of [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_transaction):
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - **`ROLLBACK`** rolls back the current transaction, canceling its changes.